# Работа с файловой системой на USB носителе

Tags: javascript, usb, kernel, osdev

Разрабатываем операционную систему JsOS.
Нужно написать драйвер для работы с ФС на USB носителе.
После нескольких недель гугления и кучи попыток понять, как это делается в ядре Linux, обратился сюда...
Подскажите, где можно найти такую информацию, желательно с примером кода.

Пока что есть возможность только определить, подключен ли носитель вообще.
Система поддерживает работу с FAT32.

Ссылка на ветку USB репозитория:
https://github.com/JsOS-Team/JsOS/tree/usb

Работа с USB находится здесь:
https://github.com/JsOS-Team/JsOS/tree/usb/js/core/usb